# Email styles breaks/gets stripped in Outlook Office 365 Mail App

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, zurb-foundation

Email template works fine in Gmail, and other email clients. Also works fine in Outlook Office 365 Mail App in **Mac**, But the styling breaks only in Outlook Office 365 Mail App in **Windows**.

I created the email templates using Zurb Foundation for emails. Still, they are not being supported in the Outlook Office 365 Mail App.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

`link to email-template:` [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Baliga/24s3nL6m/)

---

Expected output (works in Gmail and other email client):
[image]

---

Output in Outlook Office 365 Mail App in Windows (Style gets broken/stripped):
[image]

Comment: Can you also share the broken design in Windows Office.

Comment: @SudiptoRoy I've added the screenshots in the question as you've asked.

Comment: Have you accepted to download the sender's images / added them as a trusted sender in outlook?

Comment: @JGreatorex Yes I did. It still doesn't work. 
P.S: I have the same Office 365 Mail App in Mac and it works there, but not in windows.